# Virtual VNC session on Windows 7

Tags: session, windows-7, vnc

I have a windows 7 box at home that I VNC into for maintenance. That same Windows 7 box is also a HTPC (hooked up to the TV) that my kids use to watch movies while I'm at work. What I am trying to do is manage the machine without interrupting my family watching their stuff. I know I can SSH in, but would prefer something like a different session altogether.

Does anyone know if it is possible to VNC into a different session on Windows 7? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't belong here, but to answer your question: Remote desktop (built into every Windows PC) connects to a different session and has better performance than VNC.